# CSRF - logs in only the first time

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, spring-security, csrf

When I deploy my app on the server, first time I can log in without problems. But when I log out I get "403 Forbidden" on the logout post request. Then I cannot log in successfully because I get the 403 error on the login request.
Ctrl+F5, trying to log in again and... it works, but only one time.

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/apps", "/sites", "/users").authenticated()
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository())
                .and()
                .addFilterAfter(new CsrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);
}
private CsrfTokenRepository csrfTokenRepository() {
    HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository repository = new HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository();
    repository.setHeaderName("X-XSRF-TOKEN");
    return repository;
}
```

and the CsrfHeaderFilter class:

```
public class CsrfHeaderFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        CsrfToken token = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute(CsrfToken.class
                .getName());
        response.setHeader("X-CSRF-HEADER", token.getHeaderName());

        response.setHeader("X-CSRF-PARAM", token.getParameterName());

        response.setHeader("X-XSRF-TOKEN", token.getToken());

        if (token != null) {
            Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, "X-XSRF-TOKEN");
            if (cookie == null || token != null && !token.equals(cookie.getValue())) {
                cookie = new Cookie("X-XSRF-TOKEN", token.getToken());
                cookie.setPath("/");
                response.addCookie(cookie);
            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

and in Angular:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.xsrfHeaderName = 'X-XSRF-TOKEN';
```

My app is deployed at localhost:8080/myApp if it matters.

Comment: How do you do the logout?

Comment: @DoronSinai in angular I send a post request and then do this: `this.id = null;data = {}; delete $cookies.session;` and, what's funny, I can't find controller which handles /logout request in Spring. That's strange.

Comment: @DoronSinai, my mistake. There's a handler for logout request: `private static final String CURRENT_USER_ATTRIBUTE = "currentUser";
 @Override
 public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Authentication authentication)
   throws IOException, ServletException {
 httpServletRequest.getSession().removeAttribute(CURRENT_USER_ATTRIBUTE);
 httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
  httpServletResponse.getWriter().flush(); }`

Comment: Why are you deleting $cookies.session;?
Also can you see if the logout post have the XSRF token

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After certain events like `login`, `logout`, the CSRF token changes. So, the next POST request would fail, as in your case. I faced the same issue, and after some diagnosis, found that sending another GET request following `login`, `logout` etc. would be the best way to tackle it. (If you are not using CORS, you may as well have the `login`, `logout` send a redirect response). See [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31654565/spring-single-page-application-csrf-token-changing-silently-after-login-logout) for more details.

Comment: I'm shocked, it works. Do you have any explanation why?

Comment: Because the SESSION invalidates by default, the CSRF token, which is stored in the session by default, changes. See the comments in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31654565/spring-single-page-application-csrf-token-changing-silently-after-login-logout