# Spring security post request with AJAX (Logout)

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring, spring-security

As I am moving from Spring 3.1.1.RELEASE to 4.0.2 RELEASE I have had to make some changes to spring security context.

Almost everything is ok except POST Request for logout.

I could make entire line to be form method="POST" action="logout" but then I have to deal with Submit which is totally different styling then what we need.
I have tried sending logout request with csrf data over ajax with no success.
Any help is greatly appreciated. P.S. Disabling csrf is not an option.

```
 <!-- JSP -->
 <meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
<!-- default header name is X-CSRF-TOKEN -->
<meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>

<!--Anchor -->
<a id="loggg" href="logout">Logout1</a>

<!-- jquery -->
$("#loggg").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
     var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
      var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
    $.ajax({
        url : "logout",
        method : "POST",
        data :token ,
        success : function(data) { 
            console.log("clicked");
        }, 
        error : function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

})
```

FireBug developer console returns :

```
403 Forbidden 2ms
"NetworkError: 403 Forbidden - http://localhost:8081/nekretnine/logout"
Object { readyState=4,  responseText="<!DOCTYPE html><html> 
<he...EASE</h3></body></html>",  status=403,  more...}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to partially solve this issue. This answer is for those who might stumble on to the same problem as i did when i moved from Spring Security 3.1.1 to Spring security 4.0.2

JSP

```
 <meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
 <!-- default header name is X-CSRF-TOKEN -->
 <meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
```

Anchor

```
<a id="loggg" href="logout">Logout1</a>
```

Jquery

```
$("#loggg").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
     var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
      var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
    $.ajax({
        url : 'logout',
        type : 'POST',
        data: token,
        beforeSend:function(xhr){
             xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
        },
        success : function(data) { 
            window.location ="/home";    here is the only problem, for some reason after logging out page doesnt refresh and i can still see myself logged in. Then i usually just press f5 and i am logged out.
        }, 
        error : function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });

})
```

Few problems i noticed when i changed from Spring security 3 to Spring Security 4.
Here are some :

Attributes are no longer j.username i j.password instead use- username   password

2. Action is no longer j_spring_security_check  ,instead use - login
3. Logout action is no longer j_spring_security_logout use logout
4. Request must be post, even for logout.
5. U need to add CSRF token

`<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>`

to forms, or if u use spring forms, csrf.token will be added automatically. Also u can use

u need to add  these filters ( u must add them before Spring security filter)

```
<filter>
        <display-name>springMultipartFilter</display-name>
             <filter-name>springMultipartFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
             <filter-name>springMultipartFilter</filter-name>
             <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

7. You were probably using multipartResolver resolver bean, which you will need to change to 
   `<beans:bean id="filterMultipartResolver"
   class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
           <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="-1" />`
8. Also if you have done all this and you still cant upload files using commons-fileUpload you (as myself) probably placed filterMultyPartResolver in servlet-context , which was working just fine in previous version, now with no compile errors you will just end up in a dead-end street not knowing what to do. Solution is very simple, just move bean to root-context.xml and voala! all is working perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If your *login* is an AJAX request from the same page, that would have changed the token in the server. Spring Security [changes the token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31654565/spring-single-page-application-csrf-token-changing-silently-after-login-logout) in events like *login* and *logout*.

So, your token in the page would no more be valid.

If this turns out to be the case, one way would be to fetch the new token using a GET request after having a filter attaching the token as a cookie, as explained [here](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/#_csrf_protection).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31947205/csrf-logs-in-only-the-first-time) also might be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am almost certain the problem is in ajax post request. I did a small test with regular form and button instead anchor and it is working perfectly. Any thoughts?      

       <form method="POST" action="logout">
          <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Logout">Logout</button>
        <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}"/>
       </form>

Comment: Quick guess: the  `data: token` in the AJAX request seems ok? Shouldn't the token be posted either as a form parameter, in the format `_csrf:token-val` or as a header in similar format?